# Incompatible pointer types sending 'CC3MeshNode *' to parameter of type 'CCNode *'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos3d

i am new to the cocos2d/3d ,i want to draw cylinder but for understanding the functionality i am trying to  Load a meshnode of a triangle in cocos3d with help of [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14993) link, but i am getting warning  Incompatible pointer types sending 'CC3MeshNode *' to parameter of type 'CCNode *' and application crashing with below error.

please forgive for my english.

2013-03-19 12:43:49.195 LipAgumentation[982:d503] -[CC3MeshNode _setZOrder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc44cce0

2013-03-19 12:43:49.203 LipAgumentation[982:d503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CC3MeshNode _setZOrder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc44cce0'

```
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x019335a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0161b313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x019350bb -[NSObject(NSObject)     
 doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x018a4966 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x018a4522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   LipAgumentation                     0x0003d574 -[CCNode insertChild:z:] + 532
6   LipAgumentation                     0x0003cb25 -[CCNode addChild:z:tag:] + 501
7   LipAgumentation                     0x0003ce39 -[CCNode addChild:] + 313
8   LipAgumentation                     0x0020754d -[LipAgumentationLayer  
LoadMeshOfATriangle] + 1405
9   LipAgumentation                     0x00206fbd -[LipAgumentationLayer LipsEffect] + 45
10  LipAgumentation                     0x00206d3f __42-[LipAgumentationLayer  
initializeControls]_block_invoke_0 + 47
11  LipAgumentation                     0x00023b70 -[NSObject(CCBlocksAdditions)  
ccCallbackBlockWithSender:] + 48
12  CoreFoundation                      0x018a3c7d __invoking___ + 29
13  CoreFoundation                      0x018a3b51 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
14  LipAgumentation                     0x0003678f -[CCMenuItem activate] + 79
15  LipAgumentation                     0x00036ff0 -[CCMenuItemLabel activate] + 160
16  LipAgumentation                     0x00033e94 -[CCMenu ccTouchEnded:withEvent:] + 292
17  LipAgumentation                     0x00089c3a -[CCTouchDispatcher  
touches:withEvent:withTouchType:] + 1482
18  LipAgumentation                     0x0008a783 -[CCTouchDispatcher  
touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 115
19  LipAgumentation                     0x0008c53e -[EAGLView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 110
20  UIKit                               0x009a3ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
21  UIKit                               0x00984c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
22  UIKit                               0x00989f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
23  GraphicsServices                    0x02248992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
24  CoreFoundation                      0x01914944  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
25  CoreFoundation                      0x01874cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
26  CoreFoundation                      0x01871f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
27  CoreFoundation                      0x01871840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
28  CoreFoundation                      0x01871761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
29  GraphicsServices                    0x022471c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
30  GraphicsServices                    0x02247289 GSEventRun + 115
31  UIKit                               0x0098dc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
32  LipAgumentation                     0x00205ed6 main + 134
33  LipAgumentation                     0x00002bb5 start + 53
)
```

terminate called throwing an exception

here is my code to draw triangle

```
    static float arr_location[] = {-1.0,0.0,0.0,  1.0,0.0,0.0,  0.0,1.0,0.0};
static float arr_normal[] = {0.0,0.0,1.0, 0.0,0.0,1.0, 0.0,0.0,1.0};
static ushort arr_indice[] = {0,1,2};
static float arr_texture[] = {1.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0};

CC3VertexLocations *locationDemo = 
           [[CC3VertexLocations vertexArrayWithName:@"demoLocation"] autorelease];
locationDemo.drawingMode = GL_TRIANGLES;
[locationDemo setVertexCount:3];
[locationDemo setVertices:arr_location];

CC3VertexNormals *demonormal = 
        [[CC3VertexNormals vertexArrayWithName:@"demoNormal"] autorelease];
[demonormal setVertexCount:3];
[demonormal setVertices:arr_normal];

CC3VertexIndices *demoIndices = [CC3VertexIndices vertexArrayWithName: @"demoIndicies"];
demoIndices.drawingMode = GL_TRIANGLES;
[demoIndices setVertexCount:3];
[demoIndices setVertices:arr_indice];

CC3Texture *demoTex;
demoTex = [[CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"2.jpg"] autorelease];

CC3VertexTextureCoordinates *demoTexture = 
       [CC3VertexTextureCoordinates vertexArrayWithName:@"demoTexture"];
[demoIndices setVertexCount:3];
[demoIndices setVertices:arr_texture];

[demoTexture alignWithTexture:demoTex];

CC3VertexArrayMesh *demoMeshModel = 
    [[CC3VertexArrayMesh meshWithName:@"demoMeshModel"] autorelease];
demoMeshModel.vertexLocations = locationDemo;
demoMeshModel.vertexNormals = normal;
demoMeshModel.vertexIndices = demoIndices;
demoMeshModel.vertexTextureCoordinates = demoTexture;

CC3MeshNode* demoMesh = [CC3MeshNode nodeWithName:@"demoMeshNode"];
demoMesh.mesh = demoMeshModel;
demoMesh.material = [CC3Material shiny];
demoMesh.material.name = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"demoMeshNode"];
demoMesh.material.diffuseColor = CCC4FMake(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
[demoMesh.material setTexture:demoTex];

[self addChild:demoMesh];
```

Comment: You are sending a CC3MeshNode where a CCNode is expected. So you should document what are the use of CC3MeshNode and how to use them.[self addChild:demoMesh] is wrong.

Comment: i have selected cocos3d environment to create the project hen why CCNode is base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the http://brenwill.com/docs/cocos3d/0.6.2/api/interface_c_c3_node.html documentation, and you have to use a `CC3Node` base class in order to use `CC3MeshNode`.

I'm pretty sure "self" is a `CCNode` type and not a `CC3Node` base class as expected.

Comment: i have selected cocos3d environment to create the project then why CCNode is base class?

Comment: Dunno, you should read cocos3d documentation. It could have CC3Node to CCNode converter or there some adaptator class, or maybe the template is not attended to do what you want. What i'm sure is CCNode (2d) doesn't like your 3D nodes ;)